# How to display data at diffrent depths in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, overlay, arcscene, bathymetry

I am looking for a way to display data at different depths in ArcScene.

I have a bathymetry layer which displays fine, and I want to overlay oil platforms in 3D over the bathymetry to show where marine growth occurs.  I have managed to display the platforms as extrusions, but I would like to display on each platform where a particular species occurs.

For example soft coral occurring between -20 and -40 meters and hard coral between -60 and -100 meters (different for each platform).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a spatial join would be helpful.  Spatial join the bathymetry depths to each platform point.  From here you can change the symbology of each platform and then your legend can represent what species is present for the different platforms.

You can set the rules in the symbology tab to set breaks in the data to classify each platform a different symbol level.